# Parse server anonymous authentication security issue

Tags: parse-platform, dropbox-api

I want to supply my users a Dropbox access token trough my Parse server.
For the one who don't know, Dropbox access token is a string that supplies direct access to a dropbox account files, it should be secret, because if anyone finds it he can delete all the files.

My server should store many access tokens and it should supply the user the correct token, but the problem is that because the anonymous log in i'm afraid that if someone will know the parse server key, he could get all the secret dropbox access tokens.

In first place i supply the access tokens in server for security reasons and not put it hard coded to protect it.
But what's the difference if i put the parse key hard coded?

Is there a way to handle this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. If somebody knows your **ApiKey** he can query your parse server without any problem unless you use **ACL**

ACL is access control list which allows you to decide (on the application level) which users/roles can read or write to one or more parse objects or parse users. In runtime Parse will check if the logged in user has an access to read or write the object and only if it will have an access it will return the results to the client.

So i suggest you to protect your users/tokens with ACL's if you like to protect only the access tokens then i suggest you to create a separate class that will store the user access token and in this class you need to create an ACL for the relevant user only.

You can read more about ACL's in here:

[iOS SDK](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#security)

[Android SDK](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#security)

[JavaScript SDK](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#security)

Comment: I know about ACL, but as I mention, the authentication is anonymous, I need that each client will be able to access those tokens.